# How to use Android shared library in Ubuntu

Tags: android, python, linux, shared-libraries

I have an .so file which I pulled from an Android APK (Not my app, so I don't have access to the source, just the library)

I want to use this shared object on my 32 bit Ubuntu machine, and call some functions from it (Preferably with Python) . Is it possible to convert an Android .so to a Linux .so?

Or is there any simple solution to accessing the functions in the .so without resorting to a hefty virtual machine or something?

Thanks

Comment: Did you resolve this?  QEMU has an ARM emulator but I couldn't find an easy tutorial/replicable steps for installing Android.  However, here is a convincing account https://www.linaro.org/blog/core-dump/running-64bit-android-l-qemu/ .  (I also have a closed source binary.  As well as wanting to script jobs with it I don't trust it so want to run in a sandbox)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely not. It's very probably the Android you pull it from is running on the **ARM** architecture, and therefore the `.so` library was compiled for that architecture.

Unless your desktop machine is also on the ARM architecture (it's most likely x86 and it would have to be specific such as ARMv7) the `.so` binary will be incompatible on your desktop.

Depending on what the `.so` library actually is, you may be able to grab the source code and compile it for your x86 machine.

Disclaimer: Even if you obtain a library compiled for the same architecture as your desktop (from x86 phone), there is no guarantee it will work. It may rely on other libraries provided only by Android, and this may be the start of a very deep rabbit hole.

Comment: I appreciate your reply, but the .so file is not a common open source library, it is solely for a specific app and I would be unable to acquire the source. Is there any other simple options to utilize this .so file? I'd rather not attempt to reverse engineer and rewrite this monstrosity of a file.

Comment: See if you can obtain the `x86` version of the app - there are some x86 Android phones available. That would be your best bet.

Comment: is there any place I can download the x86 version without the device or using an emulator? Also, it seems like x86 for Android isn't really an official thing, so I don't think there would even be an x86 version of the app?

Comment: I want to know to fill the `deep rabbit hole`, my shared library only use stdc/c++, no other libraries.